# How to loop through two files (one text file, one json file) simultaneously in Bash?

Tags: bash, loops, shell

I am a bit struggling writing a bash script. So I got some output in few files, and I have to define a new variable. However I need to use 2 files, and one is a normal text file, the other one is a JSON one:

file.txt

```
abcd
fghi
jklm
```

file.json

```
{
   "test0": "000",
   "test1": "011",
   "test2": "022"
}
{
   "test0": "100",
   "test1": "111",
   "test2": "122"
}
{
   "test0": "200",
   "test1": "211",
   "test2": "222"
}
```

I need to define a new variable this way:

```
final='{"example":"$file.txt-output","tags":"$file.json-output"}'
```

I can't find a way for the script to run each loop simultaneously, the file.txt output get send first.

I have tried a few ways just for testing, but still getting the same, eg.:

```
paste -- ~/file.txt ~/file.json | while read -r input1 input2
do
    echo "$input1 =  $input2"
done
```

Here is what I get:

```
"abcd" = {
"fghi" = "test0":
"jklm" = "test1":
} =
{ =
"test0": "100",
"test1": "111",
"test2": "122",
}
```

The "final" variable should look like that:

```
final='{"example":"abcd","tags":{ "test0": "000", "test1": "011", "test2": "022" }'
final='{"example":"fghi","tags":{ "test0": "100", "test1": "111", "test2": "122" }'
....
```

The JSON file looks like that, there is no "," and it's not an array. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What, *exactly*, is `final` supposed to look like?

Comment: (BTW, I'll tell you right now that any answer I give will use `jq` with one of the inputs coming through `--slurpfile` or `--rawfile` and the other coming from stdin, with `-R` if it's the textual input on stdin or without it if it's the JSON one coming that way; but I need to see a concrete example of the desired output to be sure I'm understanding your question correctly before being able to construct that answer concretely).

Comment: I have updated the question. I have tried with jq, it is fine with the json file, but how can you make it work if you need to use a text file too?

Comment: Telling jq to read a text file as input is what `--rawfile` is for, which is why my comment above suggested it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jq -cs --rawfile texts file.txt '
  [$texts | split("\n")[] | select(. != "")] as $nonempty_text
  | [$nonempty_text, .]       # array with first all text lines, then all JSON 
  | transpose[]               # zip that array into (text, json) pairs
  | select(.[0] != null and .[1] != null) # ignore if we do not have both items
  | {"example": .[0], "tags": .[1]}       # otherwise emit output
' <file.json
```

...emits as output...

```json
{"example":"abcd","tags":{"test0":"000","test1":"1111","test2":"2222"}}
{"example":"fghi","tags":{"test0":"100","test1":"111","test2":"122"}}
```

As this is one line per item, a standard `while IFS= read -r final; do` loop will handle it properly.